# Spree 's latest version does this on remote - undefined method `set_preference' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Everything works perfect on my local. I installed everything appropriately on the server, and when I run `rake db:bootstrap` or `rake db:migrate`, I get this :

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `set_preference' for nil:NilClass
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/bundler/gems/spree-17e74dd1e908/core/lib/spree/preference_access.rb:18:in `set'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/bundler/gems/spree-17e74dd1e908/core/lib/spree/preference_access.rb:17:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/bundler/gems/spree-17e74dd1e908/core/lib/spree/preference_access.rb:17:in `set'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/Live-Jolly-Foods/config/initializers/jolly.rb:1
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:201
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:200
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/Live-Jolly-Foods/config/environment.rb:5
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:216
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/ruby1.8.7ee/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/ruby1.8.7ee/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/bundler/gems/spree-17e74dd1e908/core/lib/tasks/core.rake:71
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/ruby1.8.7ee/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/chrisisraw/webapps/rails/bin/rake:19
```

Anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it looks like in my extension I had this:

```
Spree::Config.set(:stylesheets => 'screen')
```

But since this was set twice? Not sure.. but if I deleted it, everything works perfectly since 'screen' is already set in the default preferences.

Then I had to make sure I ran my migrations with the ending : `RAILS_ENV='production'`

And we're golden!

Comment: I had a locale setting: Spree::Config.set(:default_locale => 'en-GB') and commented it out until the migrations ran. Works a charm now.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to remove your initializers files *initializers/whatever.rb*, just test whether spree instance exists :

```
if Spree::Config.instance
    Spree::Config.set(:stylesheets => 'screen')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error after following http://osdir.com/ml/spree-user/2009-11/msg00248.html and setting a preference to disable SSL in a file `initializers/prefs.rb`. Removing it allowed me to run my migration.

This was on my development machine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rvm. When comparing to a clean gemset which did work, the problem was that the problematic gems were BOTH in the bundle and in the gems directory. So a possible work around is to create a new gemset and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

one: Comment out everything in "config/initializers/spree_config.rb"

two: run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

three: Uncomment config/initializers/spree_config.rb

four: Run:

```
bundle exec rake db:bootstrap
```