# Spree: undefined method `preference_definitions' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, spree

I'm trying to launch an RoR app on my local machine. On running rake `db:bootstrap`, everything works fine until:

```
Create the admin user (press enter for defaults).
Email [spree@example.com]: 
Password [spree123]: 
rake aborted!
undefined method `preference_definitions' for nil:NilClass
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/app/models/preference.rb:31:in `definition'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/app/models/preference.rb:37:in `value'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activemodel-3.1.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:143:in `attribute_change'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activemodel-3.1.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `block in changes'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activemodel-3.1.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `map'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activemodel-3.1.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:117:in `changes'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:34:in `block in save!'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `tap'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:194:in `transaction'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree_core/preferences/model_hooks.rb:287:in `block (2 levels) in update_preferences'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree_core/preferences/model_hooks.rb:275:in `each'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree_core/preferences/model_hooks.rb:275:in `block in update_preferences'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree_core/preferences/model_hooks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree_core/preferences/model_hooks.rb:274:in `update_preferences'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:401:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:194:in `transaction'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/spree/preference_access.rb:20:in `set'
/home/nishant/voylla_website/db/seeds.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:488:in `load_seed'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:301:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bundler/gems/spree-22cd84cc71d9/core/lib/tasks/core.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have no idea what this means. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653803/spree-s-latest-version-does-this-on-remote-undefined-method-set-preference) link which is related to my issue. But I dunno where I can change spree configurations or RAILS_ENV. Could someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `rails g spree:install` and running migrations and seeds within that task?

Comment: nope. Lemme try. How can i run migrations within that task?

Comment: @Miotsu : `rails g spree:install` gives `Could not find generator spree:install`

Comment: this is not a good sign. I suggest you have a look at Spree's installation guide [link](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html) and Spree's github readme [link](https://github.com/spree/spree).

Comment: Is there a reason you're running such an old version of Spree?  That appears to be Spree 0.7x or earlier which is over 2 years old.

Comment: @gmacdougall : I did a bundle install thats how I got it. I did not explicitly install it.

Comment: @naka I assume this is an old legacy application that you've inherited then?

Comment: @gmacdougall : yup about an year old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue with the db. I used a separate dump to create new dbs and it worked fine.